# Groovy:unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have a Groovy script in Eclipse and I get the following at the import statement:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils
```

When I add the external commons-lang-2.4.jar to the Libraries in the build path, the error message goes away.  But if I remove it and instead add the external Class Folder that contains this and other jars, then I get the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the jar by navigating to `Preferences->Java Build Path->Libraries` and using `add External JARs`.  I don't believe Eclipse will pick up the various jar files in a folder for compilation - you may need to be explicit with each JAR, and I don't think it supports wildcards for those as command-line `javac` does these days.  (See aspects of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098911/eclipse-folder-with-jars-in-project) answer for some treatment of this, and a potentially interesting plugin).